# kohana form helper include javascript

Tags: forms, kohana, kohana-3, form-helpers

i do my forms in my views using kohana helper, but i need to include some javascript in some fields (like onclick, onblur, etc). How can i do this without giving up to kohana form helper?

for example, in pure html i have:

```
               <input class="field" type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php if (Cookie::get('email')) echo Cookie::get('email'); else echo 'AdresƒÉ Email'; ?>" onclick="if (this.value=='AdresƒÉ Email') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='AdresƒÉ Email';" />
```

and using the form helper:

```
            <?php echo Form::input('email', $email_value , array('id'=>'email', 'class'=>'field',$validator['email'])) ?>
```

which is okey, but i also want to add the onclick and onblur. any idea about how can this be done? thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add onclick, onblur to the attributes array:

```
echo Form::input('email', $email_value, array('onlick' => 'something;', 'onblur' => 'something else;'))
```

or consider using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and stop worrying about inline attributes ;)

Comment: true. adopted jquery instead :)